# Wordpress get_posts no older than a week

Tags: wordpress

i have problems getting most viewed post (tracking last week views only). The code is:

```
<?php
        $argsPVC = array(
          'order'   => 'desc',
          'posts_per_page' => 6,
          'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
          // required by PVC
          'suppress_filters' => false,
          'orderby' => 'post_views',
          'date_query' => array('after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'))),
          'fields' => ''
        );
        $most_viewed = get_posts( $argsPVC );        
      ?>
```

```
        <?php
          if( ! empty( $most_viewed ) ){
            foreach ( $most_viewed as $p ){
              $post = get_post( $p->ID );
        ?>
```

I get no posts.
And when i drop the line date_query i get the posts most viewed ever

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
'date_query' => array('after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'))),
```

use correct parameter:

```
'date_query' => array(array('after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')))),
```

See more date query examples here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters